# (Resolved )Best way to remove Draggable React component from flow without jumping?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have Note components that are rendered using `notes.map()`, each with `position: static`. The notes are draggable using `react-draggable` npm module.

The functionality I'm trying to achieve is when a note is deleted, to not affect the position of notes that have been dragged by the user. I've attempted to set `position: absolute` for notes that have been dragged. However, this causes the note to 'jump' in position once (happens when removed from flow).

-- Initial State:
[image: Initial State]
-- After first drag attempt, test note jumps on top of other note:
[image: After first drag attempt, component jumps]
-- Able to drag normally after first attempt:
[image: Able to drag normally after first attempt]

I've included relevant code for Notes.jsx component:

```
function Note(props) {
const [dragDisabled, setDragDisabled] = useState(true);
const [beenDragged, setBeenDragged] = useState(props.beenDragged);
const [position, setPosition] = useState({ xPos: props.xPos, yPos: props.yPos });

// Drag Note Functions
function handleClick() {
    setDragDisabled(prevValue => {
        return !prevValue;
    })
}

function firstDrag(event) {
    if (!beenDragged) {
        axios.post("api/note/beenDragged", {id: props.id})
            .then(setBeenDragged(true));
    }
}

function finishDrag(event, data) {
    setPosition({ xPos: data.x, yPos: data.y });
    
}

useEffect(() => {
    axios.post("/api/note/updateposition", {position, id: props.id });
}, [position]);

return <Draggable
    disabled={dragDisabled}
    onStart={firstDrag}
    onStop={finishDrag}
    defaultPosition={{ x: props.xPos, y: props.yPos }}
    // position={location}
>
    <div className='note' style={{position: beenDragged ? 'absolute' : 'static'}}>

        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        <p>{props.content}</p>

        <button onClick={handleClick}>
            {dragDisabled ? <LockIcon /> : <LockOpenIcon />}
        </button>
        <EditPopup title={props.title} content={props.content} editNote={editNote} />
        <DeletePopup deleteNote={deleteNote} />

    </div>
</Draggable>
}
```

and for my CSS styling

```
.note {
background: #fff;
/* background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/notebook-dark.png"); */
background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/lined-paper-2.png");
border-radius: 7px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgb(120, 150, 179);
padding: 10px;
width: 240px;
margin: 16px;
float: left;
}
```

Relevant code for how App.jsx renders the notes:

```
function App() {
const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

return (
    <div id="bootstrap-override">
        {notes.map((note) => {
            return <Note
                key={note._id}
                id={note._id}
                title={note.title}
                content={note.content}
                xPos={note.xPos}
                yPos={note.yPos}
                beenDragged={note.beenDragged}
                deleteNote={deleteNote}
                editNote={editNote}
            />
        })}
    </div>);
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: long codes are hard to read and understand would be better if you could upload that code on any playground such as codepen

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue not directly, but rather using a different approach to get the result I was looking for.

To summarize, I used `position: absolute` for all notes, and created them at random x,y coordinates within a boundary. This way deleted notes would not affect the position of existing notes.

Hope this helps anyone with similar issues!

Answer (score 0):

When your draggables are `position: static`, you'll experience that screen jank when removing an element because the order of the elements in the document help define where your draggables live, regardless of their dragged state (which boils down to something like `transform: translate(100px, 150px);`.

The `translate` is like saying: "go over `100px` and up `100px` from wherever you live. When we delete the first element, everybody shifts. They can still `translate(100px, 150px);` but the point from which they originate will have changed.

Someone mentioned setting the draggable's to `position: absolute` and the parent as `position: relative`. That works, but might introduce headaches of it's own.

I will offer an innocent, perhaps naive, solution: hiding the element. A quick and dirty way: instead of removing the element from the DOM, you can set the element's `visibility: none`. You can even delete the item in the backend and offer a "restore note" feature in the UI since the draggable will still contain content.

And whenever you're hiding things, make sure you do so with accessibility in mind. [Here's a good article on that](https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2017/04/14/inclusively-hidden.html).

I also made a derpy screencast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fr0PfT3Frzk&ab_channel=SamKendrick. It goes a little fast, but I begin by deleting the first element to illustrate your problem. Then I undo the delete and instead attach a `visibility: hidden` style to the element I want to delete.